# Normality condition for a DVR

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a discrete valuation ring, with characteristic not equal to $2$. Let $R[x]$ be the ring of polymomials in one variable over $R$, and fix a non-zero $a\in R$. I must find necessary and sufficient conditions on the valuation of $R$ in order for $A:=R[x,\sqrt{ax}]$ to be normal.

Called $K:=\operatorname{Frac}R$, notice that $K(x)=R(x)$. It follows that $\operatorname{Frac}A$ can be expressed as $R(x)\oplus R(x)\sqrt{ax}$. So given a $t\in \operatorname{Frac}A$, write it as $r+s\sqrt{ax}$, with $r,s\in R (x)$. The minimal polynomial of $t$ over $R(x)$ is $X^2-2rX+(r^2-s^2ax)$. *If $t$ is integral over $A$, it is integral over $R[x]$, and the coefficients $2r,r^2-s^2ax$ must be in $R[x]$*. So I should find a condition on the valuation such that $2r,r^2-s^2ax\in R[x]$ if and only if $r,s\in R[x]$, for every $r,s\in R(x)$. For example here two conditions that seem sufficient are that $2$ is a unit and $a$ is square-free. Before trying to fill the details, I would like to know if this kind of reasoning can be useful or it takes nowhere.

Edit: I see now that in the statement in *italics* I took for granted that $R[x]$ is normal, but I don't know if it's true actually.

Second edit: the exercise asked also to compute the normalization of $A$ when it's not normal, i.e. when $a$ is not square-free. Again, if I take a $t\in\operatorname{Frac}A$ and I write it as $r+s\sqrt {ax}$, where $r,s$ in $R(x)$, I have that $2r\in R [x]$ and $r^2-s^2ax\in R[x]$. So $r\in R[x]$, while $s:=\frac fg$ (with $f,g\in R[x]$) must satisfy $g\in R$ (i.e. it is a constant polynomial) and $g^2$ divides $a$. So as a solution I'd say that the integral closure of $R[x,\sqrt{ax}]$ in its field of fractions $R(x)\oplus R(x)\sqrt{ax}$ consists of the elements of the form $\frac fg +\frac hb\sqrt{ax}$, where $f,g,h\in R[x]$ and $b\in R$ such that $b^2$ divides $a$.

Comment: I don't have access to the book at the moment but I believe Lemma 4.1.18 in Liu is a criterion for schemes over Dedekind domains (in particular DVR's) to be normal. I think flat + reduced special fiber + normal generic fiber are the conditions, but look it up.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize you wanted a criterion on the valuation. I have no idea what that would look like.

Comment: What do you mean with criterion on the valuation? $p(x,y)=y^2-x^3$ gives $B=R[x,x^{3/2}]$ which is not integrally closed.

Comment: @reuns the context is that an exercise ask me to find necessary and sufficient conditions on the valuation of $R$ in order for $B$ to be normal. In the exercise I have an expression for $p(x,y)$, but I wanted to know in general how the normality of $B$ and the valuation of $R$ can link together

Comment: That's why I'm asking you to explain what you mean with $B=R[x,x^{3/2}]$.

Comment: The text of the exercise confuses me too. I have $B=R[x,\sqrt{ax}]$, for $a\in R$ non-zero. The only thing that I could think of is that I'll find some condition on $a$: for example (I know that it isn't the case, is just to give an idea) that $a$ must be invertible, and so it is sent in $0$ by the valuation. I don't know if this is the right approach

Comment: $\Bbb{Z}_p[x,\sqrt{px}]$ is integrally closed as well. But $\Bbb{Z}_p[x,\sqrt{p^2x}]$ is not. Is it your true question, to find the $a\in R$ a DVR such that $R[x,\sqrt{ax}]$ is integrally closed?

Comment: The precise question is: *suppose that $R$ is a DVR with characteristic different from $2$. Then prove that $A:=R[x,\sqrt{ax}]$, for $a\in R$ non-zero, is an integral domain, find its dimension and find necessary and sufficient conditions on the valuation of $R$ so that $A$ is normal.* Now I'm referring to the last request

Comment: Then edit your question! Restricting to $R[x,\sqrt{ax}]$ gives a simple criterion on $a$, clearly not the same as looking at $R[x,y]/(p(x,y))$ in full generality.

Comment: Ok @reuns I made the question more specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For $K$ a field then $K[x]$ is integrally closed
- If $S$ is a DVR with discrete valuation $v$ and $K=Frac(S)$ then:

  - let $Int(S[x])$ be the integral closure of $S[x]$ in $Frac(S[x])$.
  - We have the discrete valuation $w(\sum_{j=0}^J c_j t^j) = \inf_j v(c_j)$ on $S[x]$, which extends to $Frac(S[x])$.
  - let $O_w = \{ r\in Frac(S[x]):w(r)\ge 0\}$. It is a DVR, whence integrally closed, so $Int(S[x])\subset O_w$.
  - Therefore, $Int(S[x]) \subset K[x]\cap O_w = S[x]$ ie. $S[x]$ is integrally closed.

Let $v'$ be the discrete valuation of $R$.

- If $v'(a)\ge 2$ then $a = \pi^2c$ with $c\in R,\pi \in R,v'(\pi)=1$ and $A=R[x,\sqrt{ax}]$ is not integrally closed since it doesn't contain $\sqrt{cx}$ which is a root of $T^2-cx\in A[T]_{monic}$.
- If $v'(a)=1$ then $S=R[\sqrt{a}]$ is a DVR with maximal ideal $(a)$.

  $S[\sqrt{x}]$ is integrally closed and $S[\sqrt{x}]\cap Frac(A)= (A \oplus \sqrt{a} A) \cap Frac(A)=A$ so $A$ is integrally closed.
- If $v'(a)=0$ then $A= R[\sqrt{ax}]$ is integrally closed.

Comment: Thank you but could you say if my proof can be corrected easily? It seems strange that it is completely wrong if I had $a$ square-free in the solution, it's likely that I'm only having a problem with the element $2\in R$ (see my last comment)

Comment: I am not comfortable with "minimal polynomial". In my answer with $a=\pi^2c$ then $\sqrt{cx}$ is a root of both $T^2-cx$ and $\pi T-\sqrt{ax}$.

Comment: Why isn't good using the notion of minimal polynomial? I'm doing it because in our course we used quite often this theorem: let $A$ is a normal domain, $K$ is its field of fractions, and $L$ is an algebraic extension of $K$. Then $t\in L$ is integral over $A$ iff its minimal polynomial over $K$ has all coefficients in $A$. It seemed to me that in this situation we could use it too

Comment: As you wish. My answer doesn't assume any theorem.

Comment: Thank you anyway. The last question of the exercise was to compute the normalization when $A$ is not normal, I added it in an edit (I don't think that I should open another question). Even if you don't like the argument, could you tell me if the solution is correct?

Comment: reuns may I ask you some questions? 1. In the first part you proved that $S[x]$ is integrally closed; can I also use as argument that $S$ is a factorial ring (DVR$\implies$PID$\implies$UFD) and so $S[x]$ is factorial too (so integrally closed)?